# Default instances URL to execute the Open CTI JavaScript library file(Interaction.js and Opencti_min.js)

Tags: salesforce, toolkit

For executing Open CTI JavaScript library files (`interaction.js` and `opencti_min.js`) we have to specify an absolute URL to `interaction.js` or `opencti_min.js` to use the toolkit. I can't determine the org's instance, which I need to access the toolkit library by using the default instance.

So what exact default instance URL do I need to use for invoking the CTI toolkit libraries?

Classic:

```
<script src="https://c.<yourInstance>.visual.force.com/support/api/46.0/interaction.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Lightning:

```
<script src="https://c.<yourInstance>.visual.force.com/support/api/46.0/lightning/opencti_min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In the above mentioned URL, what exact `<YourInstance>` value do I have to use as a default absolute URL?

Comment: Hi, Did you understand how to do it?
Same here...